# What do Bitset size() and length() mean, and what is the difference between them?

Tags: java, bitset

I don't quite understand the different meanings of `size()` and `length()` in `BitSet`. Check the code below:

```
public class Sandbox {

   public static void main(String argv[]) 
   {
       BitSet bitSet1 = new BitSet(16);
       bitSet1.set(0);
       bitSet1.set(8);
       bitSet1.set(15);
       displayBitSet(bitSet1);
       
    
 
   }
   
   static void displayBitSet(BitSet bitSet)
   {
       for(int i=0;i<bitSet.size();i++)
       {
           boolean bit = bitSet.get(i);
           System.out.print(bit?1:0);
       }
       System.out.println(" "+bitSet.size()+" "+bitSet.length());
   }
 
}
```

Output is:

```
1000000010000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64 16
```

I thought I would get something like

```
1000000010000001 16 16
```

Where do these trailing zeroes come from? Can someone explain this to me? thanks~~

Comment: if you only want 'your' bits printed, loop like `for(int i=0;i<bitSet.length();i++)`. But `size()` will still return 64. Are you on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: The trailing zeros come from the internal data structure of BitSet. Eventhough you want 16 Bits, it allocates 64, but probably only lets you use the first 16. Would `bitSet1.set(28);` result in an error?

Comment: "Is BitSet the equivalent of BitArray in Java?" - no. Bitset can not contains equivalent items and bit array can... And I think that 64 is buffered size. if you push into set too much the size must automaticly changes

Comment: bitSet1.set(28); does not result in any error...Interestingly enough, when I try bitSet1.set(64); here is the output: 10000000100000010000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 128 65

Comment: I think that , like Aleksei says, size automatically changes

Comment: I'm munging your title.  Google thinks this post is documentation for BitSet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer is quite simple the `BitSet` constructor just says it generates something which is big enough to the given size, actually it takes some internal size which is best matching.

And in your case this is 64 bit, see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you see the documentation of [`BitSet#size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size%28%29), it says:

> Returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to
>   represent bit values. The maximum element in the set is the size - 1st
>   element.

And for [`BitSet#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length%28%29):

> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest
>   set bit in the BitSet plus one. Returns zero if the BitSet contains no
>   set bits.

So, you should use `BitSet.length`, if you want to get the actual number of `bits` in your bitset. Because, `BitSet.size` returns the memory occupied by your `BitSet` instance.

Also, according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet%28%29):

> Note that the size is related to the implementation of a bit set, so
>   it may change with implementation

So the size in your case is 64 bit, which can change automatically, when you set bit at index greater than specified length.